# Spring-Statemachine: Access to PseudoStates, that are skipped

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

First of all, my primary goal is to illustrate a state machine diagram.

The method `StateMachineFactory<S, E>#getStateMachine()` builds a new instance of my stateMachine. The  `StateMachine<S, E>` has a lot of methods, such as `getStates(): Collection<State<S, E>>` and `getTransitions(): Collection<Transition<S,E>>`.

In order to create a simple state machine diagram I need all states associated with their transistions. The above method `getStates()` gives me all States, but the method `getTransitions()` doesn't give me all transistions.

For example in order to understand, what I mean. The following state machine diagram is given and the corresponding statemachine `machine`:
[image]

The follwoing methods gives me as result:

- `machine.getInitialState()` --> `State_A`
- `machine.getStates()` --> `State_A`, `State_B`, `State_C`, `State_D`, `State_E` and `Choice`
- `machine.getTransitions`

  - `State_A` --> `Choice`
  - `Stabe_B` --> `State_D`
  - `State_C` --> `State_E`

How can I get the remaining transistions from `Choice` --> `State_B` and `Choice` --> `State_C` ?

The [Javdoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/transition/Transition.html) describes a transitionas as something what a state machine associates with a state changes.  What does this exactly mean?

Last but not least, how can i go through states and transistions of my state machine and logging the guards, transitions and all other stuff without mocking the whole triggering events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more like 3 questions, instead of one, but here we go:

> How can I get the remaining transistions from Choice --> State_B and
>   Choice --> State_C ?

If you want to have full access to the StateMachineConfig you have to look into the [`StateMachineModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/StateMachineModel.html).
One way is to define your own [StateMachineModelVerifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/verifier/StateMachineModelVerifier.html), call super(), and read whatever you need from the model:

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
        throws Exception {
    config
        .withVerifier()
            .enabled(true)
            .verifier(cusomVerifier());
}

@Bean    
public StateMachineModelVerifier customVerifier() {
  return new CustomVerifier();
}

class CustomVerifier extends DefaultStateMachineModelVerifier {
  @Override
  public void verify(StateMachineModel model) {
    super.verify(model); // call the existing sanity check model verifier
    TransitionsData<S,E> transitions = model.getTransitionsData();
  }
}
```

Through [`TransitionsData`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/TransitionsData.html) you can get all Choices etc.

> The Javdoc describes a transitionas as something what a state machine
>   associates with a state changes. What does this exactly mean?

Entering a Choice Or Junction does not actually trigger state transition.
These are pseudo states where conditions are evaluated, based on which the SM decides where to transition next.

E.g. in your case State A -> Choice -> State B or State C

The possible transitions are:

- A -> B
- A -> C

There's no A -> Choice; Choice -> B; Choice -> C

> Last but not least, how can i go through states and transistions of my
>   state machine and logging the guards, transitions and all other stuff
>   without mocking the whole triggering events?

I don't fully understand your question but consider:

- logging guards - implement logging in the guard methods themselves;
- logging SM transitions with your own listener (see sample below);

## Registering Listener

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config) throws Exception {
  config.withConfiguration().listener(stateChangeListener());
}

private StateMachineListenerAdapter stateChangeListener() {
   return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events> () {

        //Override what's necessary, but particularly
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(State<S,E> from, State<S,E> to) {
            //logging
        }
   }
}
```

## Stepping Through State Machine

Consider using [`StateMachineTestPlan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/test/StateMachineTestPlan.html) ([official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-test), which contains code samples)